# Is it possible to create a QBXML VendorMod request for Vendors with a matching Custom Field (DataExt) value?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm attempting to update QuickBooks Vendor records using QBXML and Web Connector.

From the system in which I'm generating the QBXML requests, I don't have ready access to the QuickBooks Vendor `ListID`, but I do have access to a unique identifier that we store in a custom field (`DataExt`) in the QuickBooks Vendor record.  Is it possible to create a `VendorMod` request that will update the Vendor record(s) that have this unique value in a custom field?

I've scoured the [OSR](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html) and the [SDK guide](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBSDK_ProGuide.pdf) to no avail.

And if the answer is no, then what's the best way to proceed?  Start with a `VendorQuery` request, sort through the Vendors in the response, then create a `VendorMod` request using the ListID of the matching Vendor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a VendorMod request that will update the Vendor record(s) that have this unique value in a custom field?

No, this is not possible.

> And if the answer is no, then what's the best way to proceed?

Since QuickBooks won't let you query based on the custom field value, your best bet is probably to:

- Change your application so you can store the `ListID` value
- Do a one-time migration process that pulls all the Vendors from
  QuickBooks, and stores their `ListID`s
- Move forward using the `ListID`
  values to do the `VendorMod` requests